# Google Drive API V2 , Python — create new file without uploading new file and without using Google Drive UI

Tags: google-app-engine, google-drive-api

All the documentation I have found related to creating a new file and putting the new file in a user's Google Drive folder is achieved with the user uploading a file and having the python script use MediaFileUpload to gather the file and put it in Drive.

I want to create a new file in my GAE code, and put that. For example my code renders a new XML string after hitting database, and I would like to take that string, make it a file and put in Google Drive.

Anyone working with something like this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use a MediaInMemoryUpload instead, which is designed for this exact purpose. You can pass a string and a MIME type.

```
media = MediaInMemoryUpload('some data', 'text/plain')
```

Comment: DEPRECATED: Use MediaIoBaseUpload with either io.TextIOBase or StringIO for the stream.
http://google.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/epy/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Use following code, content is the string you're going to put. You don't have to use MediaFileUpload and python client library.

```
def update(content, file_id):
    url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v2/files/%s?uploadType=media' % file_id
    headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'text/plain',
        'Content-Length': str(len(content)),
        'Authorization': 'Bearer <oauth2 token>'
        }
    response = urlfetch.fetch(url, payload=content, method='PUT', headers=headers)
    assert response.status_code == 200
    return response.content
```

Comment: That works if 1. you don't need to add metadata, e.g., description, and 2. with files <= 2MB in size.

Comment: Yes, if you want to add metadata, please POST a metadata to create a new file before call this function; or POST a multi-part body to upload a file with metadata. (but I haven't get success on that yet.)

Comment: eric.f, are you doing this: https://developers.google.com/drive/manage-uploads#using_multipart_upload

Comment: Yes. This is the default upload type for the Python API client library. What is your error? Or make a new question so we can get you up and running.